# Getting error event with event ID 5719 every four hours on member server having 2012 R2 intsalled

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Getting error event with event ID 5719 every four hours on member server having 2012 R2 intsalled. Sometimes not able to login with domain credentials & server needs to be restarted after clearing the DNS cache after which domain log in works.

Please find below error message as taken from eventviewer.  Event ID 5719

This computer was not able to set up a secure session with a domain controller in domain xyz due to the following: 
There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request. 
This may lead to authentication problems. Make sure that this computer is connected to the network. If the problem persists, please contact your domain administrator.

ADDITIONAL INFO 
If this computer is a domain controller for the specified domain, it sets up the secure session to the primary domain controller emulator in the specified domain. Otherwise, this computer sets up the secure session to any domain controller in the specified domain.